# Infinite Loop from Promise and useState Hook

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-hooks

I've managed to accidentally create an infinite loop out of a fetch promise and a useState hook in react. Can anyone point out *why* this is repeating? My grasp of both pieces is a little weak, and I imagine that a clear explanation with correctly functioning code would help me see how both work.

FYI - the loreReturn variable is an object with some transaction ids, and the getData function goes and grabs some text from the web using those ids.

```
export function TextExample(){
  let testText = "no itemLore yet";
  const [text, textAdd] = useState(testText);
    const txs = loreReturn.data.transactions.edges;
    txs.forEach ((tx) => {arweave.transactions.getData(tx.node.id, {decode: true, string: true}).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        textAdd(text + data);
    });
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{text}</p>
    <
/div>
  ); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your API calls inside a `useEffect` hook and add necessary dependencies. This will make sure you are not repeatedly running the API calls every time the component reloads

```
export function TextExample(){
  let testText = "no itemLore yet";
  const [text, textAdd] = useState(testText);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const txs = loreReturn.data.transactions.edges;
    txs.forEach ((tx) => {
        arweave.transactions.getData(tx.node.id, {decode: true, string: true})
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                textAdd(text + data);
      });
    });
  }, [])
    
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  ); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this! To clarify, the react hook is set up to load over and over again and constantly update state, so the fact that I’ve put textAdd inside the API means that it has to run that fetch over and over, and it prints the result each time?

Comment: Question - the loreReturn object has more than one transaction to forEach loop through. Currently, it looks like this fix logs each transaction in the console, but only updates the useState hook with one transaction. It's unpredictable which transaction is displayed, presumably the one that happens to be delivered first? or last?  Any idea how to sequentially update the useState hook to display each transaction, one after another?

Comment: @GhostOutfit The state variables, in this case, `text` is the state variable and it does not update in real-time, it may time some time to update the value. so suggest you set the required values to a normal variable and set the value to the state after completing all the operations